# Build.xml excluding workflows

Tags: deployment, ant

We are doing build into production through jenkins cloudbees. The initial build is done. Now we have to do another build but there are already many time based workflows open in production which we cannot delete. Can we exclude workflows and do build into production as we have done some code changes and would like to do a build again into production through cloudbees.

sf.deploymentRoot=MCPM_SPRTDEV (Root project folder including workflows)

----build.xml-----

```
  <target name="deployCode">
      <!-- deploy the contents -->
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
                 serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}"
                 deployRoot="${sf.deploymentRoot}/src" testLevel="RunLocalTests" checkonly="false"> 
      </sf:deploy>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ashwin,

I dont have any experience with Cloudbees but you can definitely ignore whatever workflows you want and deploy partials as you see fit. The API servers merges your deployments successfully with whatever you already have in destination Org (or overwrite existing metadata).

If you are trying to delete something, you will need to execute a delete() and not a deploy().

If you need to speak to me about it, please feel free to contact me over twitter (sridharsa).

Good luck.

Sridhar